# Update trigger when date is current date

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

How to update trigger based on date?

I have three columns consisting of `original price` , `offer price` and `date`.

If the date expires, `offer price` column should update the original price value.

Answer (score 0):

it can't be done with trigger as that is based on Update/Insert/delete.

you can make one event that run every day and check that which ever column has date < now() that row has to update offer price = original price value.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger whenever a row is updated, inserted or deleted with actions of before or after. As when a date is expired your database doesn't know about it as no operation is performed over any row.
What you can do is taking a column with the name as is_offer_expired and create a cron job and run it once in 24hr and check what all offers are expired and perform the operation of changing your offer price with original price. That's how you will also be able to get the expired offers to count if required in the future.